# how to detect is NSMutableAttributedString attribute NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName available to use?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablestring

I mean detect is i'm able to use attribute `NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` `ofNSMutableAttributedString` like:

```
if ([object responseToSelector:@selector(someSelector)])
```

or like:

```
if ([SomeNewClass class])
```

i don't wan't compare system version, but i wan't check exactly this item;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName` is available from iOS 6 so if you are supporting 6 and above you have no worries.

Apple also uses [weak linking](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/WeakLinking.html). This sets symbols that aren't available in the current version of the OS to `NULL`. So, you can test the symbol to see if it exists with:

```
if (NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName != nil) {
    // use NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
}
```